# why simple for loop with if condition is faster than conditional generator expression in python

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Why is this for loop with if condition in first case is more than 2 times faster than second case with a conditional generator expression?

```
%%timeit
for i in range(100000):
    if i < 10000:
        continue
    pass
```

clocks at 100 loops, best of 3: 2.85 ms per loop, while using generator expression:

```
%%timeit
for i in (i for i in range(100000) if i >= 10000):
    pass
```

100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 ms per loop

Comment: I'd guess because you go twice through the values in the second version. (1 `for` vs 2 `for`'s)

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with `big-o`.

Comment: The big o tag does not apply unless you are looking at lots of different loop sizes.

Comment: Why do you expect any other result? Even if they're equivalent code otherwise, abstraction layers (when they can't be optimized out at compile time) have overhead. *That doesn't mean they aren't worth using.*

Comment: @CharlesDuffy because it would not have to create entire list to loop on

Comment: Which version of Python? In Python 3, `range()` *doesn't* create an entire list.

Comment: Even then, though it doesn't surprise me. Look at the bytecode for each.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry i was thinking(and timed) in python2

Answer (score 1):

**First version**: For each element in range: assign it to `i`.

**Second version**: For each element in range: assign it to inner `i` (third one from the left), evaluate expression `i` (the `i` from `...(i for...` assign result to "outer" (leftmost) `i`.

The `if` statements have probably a similar performance impact in both versions.

Comment: also, each iteration has to check for `StopIteration` from its iterator. That doubles the overhead as well.