# Is the `all` Python built-in function faster than its equivalent loop?

Tags: python, performance

I'm concerned about speed in my program and I couldn't find enough info about its speed. I'm certain it has a difference, but is it worth it?

Here is the equivalent according to docs

```py
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Why not find out yourself? The [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module can be used to implement this sort of comparison.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that a pure Python version would be significantly faster than a built-in, so there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It depends on your `iterable`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576180/all-vs-for-loop-with-break-performance and https://www.katrin-affolter.ch/de/programming/performance-of-all-and-any.

But in general I doubt the difference here is the source of any bottlenecks in your program. I would use profilers to identify more important places to focus your performance improvements.

Comment: It's implemented in C, you can't loop in Python anywhere near as fast as in C.

Comment: The built-in short-circuits just like this version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) particularly [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711683/53341)

Comment: @MatBailie you stand with an incorrect impression of what Python or other dynamic languages are. The "nowhere near" kind of comment only applies for integer operations where Python operates with full-featured objects against native integers in some other languages. The difference between both `all` builtin and a plain Python implementation is around 25% , not orders of magnitude as you appear to be regarding.

Comment: (ok, up to 100% slower with "real sequences"  - my first example had a 0 at the first element) But 100% is when I use a list, and the C version of "all" will use some shortcuts to get to the list elements. When using an iterator, like range, the difference is back to ~30% : even the C code will use the same paths Python code use to get an iterator's next element.

Comment: Seems this is an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). When you say: "I'm concerned about speed in my program" you shouldn't be using python. If `all` is what's slowing your code down so much you may want to consdider using something like [numpy](https://numpy.org/) or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Or it isn't even the `all` function call at all and you need to do some profiling to find the slow down

Comment: I cannot think of any circumstance where (re)writing the functionality of a Python built-in function in pure Python is going to give any performance benefit

Comment: @jsbueno *"the C version of "all" will use some shortcuts to get to the list elements"* - Please link to that code. I don't see any such optimization, and the difference is likely just because `range` is a much slower iterable than a list.

Comment: @CtrlZ See [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU87DsIwDN1zirelQQUBXRCCkyCGAI6IRD5K3aFCnISlC9yFI3AbEgoeLNl-H7_7M_Z8Dn4YHh2b6er9Mik4sHVkGdbFkBiJImkWoiXuIraQUooTGbjeWV_pGge1FsiVMiB5HGBNbhto0KUlaFEYwoSEYzgRrMdOFuqixlLJGnJUGsc9JmiKHmersh7tq0Kt8f1BqXyOyXqujLzyZEHNupnNzQ2-RdYrUDUG-uX65_sA). Python reimplementation of `min(a, b)` being over three times faster.

Comment: @nocomment That's not a fair comparison. The re-implementation in that code only handles a very specific case - i.e., min(x,y) whereas the built-in min() can handle iterables, allow for a default value and also a custom key comparison function

Comment: @CtrlZ I know, but if that's the case you need (you very well might, it's a very common case), and you want it fast, then you're better off with the Python version. And even better off with inlining the expression or an if statement. I've done that multiple times because min is so slow.

Answer (score 3):

There would be no meaningful difference in using a pure Python versions. Yes, it would be a bit slower, but still, the overhead for such simple code won't make a difference for any task you have at hand.

And then, why would one waste time recreating a perfectly good function that is already more efficient?

Of course, you could check the numbers yourself using the `timeit` module, which automatically repeats a piece of code (by default 1_000_000 times) and spills some stats:

```
In [1]: from timeit import timeit

In [2]: timeit("all(range(1, 1000))", number=100_000)
Out[2]: 2.2896956456825137


In [3]: def myall(iterable):
   ...:     for item in iterable:
   ...:         if not item: return False
   ...:     return True
In [4]: timeit("myall(range(1, 1000))", number=100_000, globals=globals())
Out[4]: 3.4623720655217767
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the performance you can use the `timeit` module

```py
import timeit

def custom_all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True

test1 = [True] * 1000000
test2 = [True] * 999999 + [False]

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: custom_all(test1), number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: all(test1), number=1000))
```

Output:

```
13.31273860001238
3.087746800039895
```

Compare with a case where the result is `False`:

```py
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: custom_all(test2), number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: all(test2), number=1000))
```

Output:

```
12.978889200021513
3.0330674999859184
```

As you can see the built-in function is significantly faster.

Comment: which Python version did you use? I just got a much smaller difference in Python 3.12 - actually, with equivalent times when the passed iterable is a list.

Comment: I used Python 3.11.5

Comment: When I use Python 3.12.0 I also get similar results.

Comment: @jsbueno What do you mean with "when the passed iterable is a list"? It **is** a list here. Are you talking about a different program?

Comment: I've tried it with `list` and a `range` instance - so I am talking about my tests.

Comment: @jsbueno `range` is much slower, so a smaller relative difference is expected. What did you mean with "equivalent times"? `all` and loop were equivalent? Or you got times equivalent to this answer?

Comment: "all" and :loop" are within 100% difference - i.e. a Python loop in Python 3.12 is less than twice as slow as "all" in the worst case scenario, and within 30% of difference for generic iterators, like "range".

Comment: @jsbueno `range` is not an iterator, and as far as I see, `all` treats both lists and ranges just like every other iterable: ask them for an iterator and use that to iterate them.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3.12 I get similar results between the built in function and the custom function with the built in function being ever so slightly faster..

Create two arrays, one which has a null value near the end:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(100000)
arr_w_null = arr.copy()
arr_w_null[-1000] = np.nan
```

Create all function and compare times:

```
def all_func(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True

# Time the functions
%%timeit -r 10 -n 500
all(arr)
## 3.98 ms ± 77.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 500 loops each)

%%timeit -r 10 -n 500
all(arr_w_null)
## 4 ms ± 81.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 500 loops each)

%%timeit -r 10 -n 500
all_func(arr)
## 4.18 ms ± 25.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 500 loops each)

%%timeit -r 10 -n 500
all_func(arr_w_null)
## 4.19 ms ± 53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 500 loops each)
```